# Bundler & Minifier generating "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I trying bundle and minify my CSS and JS files in ASP.NET Core 3.0 with `BuildBundlerMinifier.Core`.
Also Installed `Bundler & Minifier` extension for Visual Studio 2019.

When I try Debug the project, it working correctly without error but when I rebuild it, I'm getting the following error;

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

[image]

I don't get an error when restart Visual Studio and I can debug the project again but If I rebuild it again, I'm getting the error.

It's `bundleconfig.json` file

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/assets/css/style.bundle.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.css",
      "wwwroot/assets/css/style.bundle.css",
      "wwwroot/assets/css/skins/header/base/light.css",
      "wwwroot/assets/css/skins/header/menu/light.css",
      "wwwroot/assets/css/skins/brand/light.css"
    ],
    "sourceMap": false,
    "sourceMapRootPath": null
  }
,
{
  "outputFileName": "wwwroot/assets/js/scripts.min.js",
  "inputFiles": [
    "wwwroot/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js",
    "wwwroot/assets/js/scripts.js",
    "wwwroot/assets/js/pages/dashboard.js",
    "wwwroot/content/js/mobil-detect.js",
    "wwwroot/content/js/lazy-img.js",
    "wwwroot/content/js/ziyaretci.js"
  ]
}
]
```

[image]

Visual Studio, Bundler & Minifier extension, BuildBundlerMinifier and BuildBundlerMinifier.Core are up to date
How can I fix it ?

Comment: `sourceMapRootPath` is set to null. Maybe this is causing the tool to error?

Comment: I removed sourceMapRootPath. it sometimes can building, sometimes return error. I can't understand @Oliver

Comment: All the input files are in the directories? Are the input files static i.e do they get generated or are they simply always there?

Comment: Yes, all input files are in the directories and static files. @Oliver

Comment: Got the latest versions of the bundler nuget packages?

Comment: I've Installed BuildBundlerMinifier and BuildBundlerMinifier.Core from nuget and I just  removed BuildBundlerMinifier,  now  it's OK. Thank you for your interest @Oliver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The project has BuildBundlerMinifier and BuildBundlerMinifier.Core. I removed BuildBundlerMinifier from nuget and now it works.

Comment: How do you managed to bundle on build or file change then?

Comment: Where did you get BuildBundlerMinifier.Core? It's not on NuGet.org. At least not anymore.

Comment: This is an incorrect suggestion - the root cause is generally - "a presence of es6 operators in an es5 code"

Answer (score 15):

This can be an issue with the syntax in the source of one of your js files.
In my case, using the nullish coalescing operator "??" was the issue.
Replaced it with a simple "if" null check and the compilation error disappeared.

Comment: Can you please guide me on where we add a question mark, input, or output file?

Comment: Yes I had this issue with the following line of code, and removing the "?" fixed it: ```let text = descriptionfield?.find("INPUT,SELECT,TEXTAREA").val();```

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was because of the optional chaining operator, i.e. `?`.

Comment: It does answer the question in the top of the page. I had exactly the same problem: null reference exception while minifying JS files using the BundlerMinifier.Core. And the problem was in ? operator inside my JS. After I have removed it minification worked fine. I think it could be usefull and helpful for the others, because I've spent some time to figure out which of the JS files contained error and which line it was.

Comment: Hm, as I understand, you considered a question mark as a question, but it was a JS operator. I will add quotes to make it more obvious.

Comment: Ah, good point. Yes I think you saw right through me. Allow me to show you the usually used formatting for an operator, i.e. code. (Hope I got it right, because the other answer use non-standalone `?`. But that is probably the point of your post... ;-) ) I like the way in which this post fooled me so much that I want to upvote. Sadly I have to admit at 0 knowledge on the technological field here and hence should not. I hope my respect for professional reaction is also appreciated feedback for you. Have fun.

Comment: upvoting ! the presence of es6 characters in an es5 code throws this exception

Comment: For me it was the presence of `?.` which I've had in there for a long time and it gave me no trouble, then suddenly this morning it started failing. I continued to have trouble until I found out I had also used `??` in that file. Either of those will cause the Bundler & Minifier to fail. I have no idea why it has worked for the better part of a year without issue but just failed this morning. I had built the solution last night with no errors.

Answer (score 7):

Solved by refactoring all "??" nullish coalescing operators with "?:" conditional (ternary) operators.

Comment: Can you please guide me on where we add a question mark, input, or output file?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen (like me) to have a hash (#) somewhere in your directory name minification will be broken with .NET Core 3.1 using BuildBundlerMinifier.

It took me some time to figure that out including uninstalling and reinstalling nuget packages and Visual Studio extensions.

I'm wondering if there are also other special characters causing the issue.

You can easily see this in *bundleconfig.json*.

Example folder structure:

```
C:\MyProjects\C#Test\MySolution\MyProject\wwwroot\js\
```

If broken it will look like:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "#Test\\MySolution\\MyProject\\wwwroot\\js\\Math.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "#Test\\MySolution\\MyProject\\wwwroot\\js\\Math.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

instead of

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/Math.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/Math.js"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting `renameLocals` to false fixed the error. The default value is false so if this property is not in your config you don't need to worry about this being the cause. Config snippet for reference:

```
{
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/bundles/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened when i try to update my bootstrap form 4.6.2 to 5.x. When i back to default it work. My version is ASP.NET core 6